Popup form not to reappear when page refreshes
I have a popup form that loads when the page first loads in the browser. User requires to complete the form, click submit and the form then closes. At the moment, if the page is refreshed, the popup form opens again. I would like the popup form to remain closed even if the the page is refreshed. This form is for a demonstration only (educational), it doesn't require validation nor does the data need to be sent anywhere.
Thanks in advance.
I am not sure where to look or what I should be looking for in terms of code required to achieve this.
This is my HTML & JS code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginPopup">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input id="button" type="submit" value="Log In">
        </form>
      </div>
      <script src="app1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



$(function() {
    $('#loginPopup').hide();
    $('#loginPopup').show(2000);
});

$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#loginPopup').css('display', 'none');
})


you can utilize web storage, such as localStorage or sessionStorage, to keep track of whether the form has been submitted.

we need to use storage or cookies here to maintain the state of the form .If the state is not saved we can lose it every time the page is refreshed, and the form would reappear.
    // Check if the form has already been submitted
    if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted')) {
        $('#loginPopup').hide(); // Hide the form if it has been submitted
    } else {
        $('#loginPopup').show(2000); // Show the form if it hasn't been submitted
    }

    $('#button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#loginPopup').hide(); // Hide the form when submitted
        localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', true); // Set a flag in localStorage indicating the form has been submitted
    });
});


Why not hide default and only show if localStorage does not have formSubmitted?

You're absolutely right, hiding the popup by default and only showing it if localStorage does not have the formSubmitted flag set is also an efficient approach. The popup form will remain hidden by default, and it will only be shown if the formSubmitted flag is not found in localStorage. Either ways this can be achieved

Thanks very much. Your code suggestion does the trick. Much appreciated.
